# icCube driver not found: org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: java, postgresql, iccube

I'm trying to evaluate icCube and I have a problem when I try to connect a PostgreSQL datasource. When I test the connection I get an error message about PostgreSQL driver missing:

```
Failed to establish the connection due to the error: JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver' not found in the classpath
```

I've checked the lib directory of icCube and it has postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.jar bundled in the release, is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I had to add the PostgreSQL JDBC driver to bin/icCube.sh in the JDBC section:

```
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$ICCUBE/lib/postgresql-9.4.1207.jre7.jar"
```